# reset checkbox group with action button

Tags: r, button, shiny, action, shinydashboard

i've seen several entries regarding this issue and have tried several of them, but nothing has worked without either an error or just not at all...

i have a checkbox group in my shiny dashboard body

```
checkboxGroupInput("dbr", selected = NULL,
                    h4("Select Data Breach Rating"),
                    c(
                      "Low" = "Low",
                      "Medium" = "Medium",
                      "High" = "High",
                      "Critical" = "Critical"
                       # End check list 
                       ), 
                      # End check group
                      ),
```

i also have a reset button in the dashboard body using an action button

```
actionButton("reset_artifact_entry", label = "Reset")
```

in the server portion of the code i have an observeEvent

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

# Rest button for artifact entry page
    observeEvent(input$reset_artifact_entry, {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dbr", selected = NULL)
        
    })
```

I'm sure the problem is in how i have this set up...
when i run the code i get no errors, but when i click the button nothing happens either...

cheers ~!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the same choices inside you `updateCheckboxGroupInput` and then it will work. See below.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  wellPanel(checkboxGroupInput("dbr", selected = NULL,
                               h4("Select Data Breach Rating"),
                               c("Low" = "Low",
                                 "Medium" = "Medium",
                                 "High" = "High",
                                 "Critical" = "Critical")),
  actionButton("reset_artifact_entry", label = "Reset")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Rest button for artifact entry page
  observeEvent(input$reset_artifact_entry, {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dbr", choices = c(
      "Low" = "Low",
      "Medium" = "Medium",
      "High" = "High",
      "Critical" = "Critical"), selected = NULL)})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: holy crap - adding this to the primary set of code...

Comment: thanks a billions - i can now move forward with my work...

Comment: Glad it helps. :)